# Star-mesh transformation in Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, physics, reference-request

Are there possibly mathematica modules that perform the [star-mesh transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-mesh_transform), in the context of electrical circuit theory? Given a resistor network/graph as input.

**More context**:

---

We start off with a graph $G$ of $n$ nodes and a total of $n(n-1)/2$ undirected edges. To each edge, between nodes $i$ and $j$, a value $f_{ij}$ is assigned,  with $f$ a given function $f:i,j\to \mathbb{R}$ [*]. If for a given pair of nodes, their edge value is less than a given threshold (so $f<\delta$) then they are considered as disconnected.

Now with the graph $G$ defined as given above, we want to perform the star-mesh transformation on the graph, until a single edge is left. Question was, whether Mathematica has relevant built-in modules that would be considerably helpful in implementing the star-mesh transformation (which in short, keeps removing nodes and updating the edge set and edge values afterwards [**]).

[*]: Any dummy function may be chosen for the purposes of illustration. For instance, a simple function that takes as input the distance between two nodes as input.

[**]: Additional details: For a generic graph $G,$ sequentially, a node is removed (for instance starting from the node with least neighbours), and upon each removal, additional (edges)weights are introduced as follows: if the removen node (r) has $x$ neighbours, then $x(x-1)/2$ weights between each pair of its neighbours are updated. For each pair $a,b$ of its neighbours there can be only two cases:

- $a,b$ were already conneted to one another by an edge with weight $w_0,$ in which case their weight is updated to $w=w_0+w_{ra}w_{rb}/\sum_i w_{ri}$ where the sum goes over all neighbours of $r.$
- $a,b$ were not previously connected, in which case an edge is added between them with the weight $w=w_{ra}w_{rb}/\sum_i w_{ri}.$

Comment: What is the input and what is thee expected output? To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**.

Comment: @rhermans thanks for the feedback. Sure, I have tried to express things more clearly, and edited the post.

Comment: So are you happy with a weighted `Graph` then, where the weights represent resistances?

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed, I should have described it as a weighted graph from get-go.

Comment: @Szabolcs done, thanks for the good questions.

Comment: @Szabolcs indeed, that's a mistake in Wikipedia's article. The summation should be in the denominator.

Comment: I think that's correct, but it's for resistance. Your formula is for conductance.

Comment: @Szabolcs oh, i think you may be right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us represent the network with its weighted adjacency matrix. The matrix elements will be the conductances.

Then `starMesh[matrix, i]` will perform the transformation using node `i` as the star centre.

```
removeNode[matrix_, i_] := Delete[Delete[#, i] & /@ matrix, i]

zeroDiagonal[m_] := UpperTriangularize[m, 1] + LowerTriangularize[m, -1]

starMesh[matrix_?SymmetricMatrixQ, i_] :=     
 Module[{res = matrix, ind, star, mesh},
  ind = Flatten@Position[matrix[[i]], _?Positive, {1}];
  star = matrix[[i, ind]];
  mesh = zeroDiagonal@Outer[Times, star, star] / Total[star];
  res[[ind, ind]] += mesh;
  removeNode[res, i]
 ]
```

`removeNode[matrix, i]` is a helper function that deletes the `i`th row and column of the matrix. This is used to remove the star centre.

`zeroDiagonal[matrix]` is a helper function that replaces the diagonal of `matrix` with zeros.

In `starMesh`, `ind` is the indexes of nodes connected to `i` (i.e. nonzero elements in the matrix—I used `Positive` for simplicity).

`star` is a vector containing the impedances in the star structure.

`mesh` is the weighted adjacency matrix of the mesh.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried this on two dummy adjacency matrices (4 by 4), one symbolic `m={{0, a, b, c}, {a, 0, 0, d}, {b, 0, 0, 0}, {c, d, 0, 0}}` and one numerical `m2={{0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 0, 4}, {2, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 4, 0, 0}}`. And called `starMesh[m,0]` or `starMesh[m2,0]`. For both it gives the same error of e.g., "`Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>`". Is my example bad?